# C++ Member variables confusion

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ (coming from Java) and this is bugging the hell out of me, say I have...

```
class Foo {

public:

    Bar &x; // <- This is a ref, Bar is not instantiated (this is just a placeholder)
    Bar *y; // <- This is a pointer, Bar is not instantiated (this is just another placeholder)
    Bar z;  // <- What is this???

};

class Bar {

public:

    Bar(int bunchOfCrap, int thatNeedsToBeHere, double toMakeABar);

};
```

In this example Bar has one constructor that needs a bunch of fields specified in order to create a "Bar." Neither x, nor y creates a Bar, I understand that x creates a reference that can be pointed to a Bar and that y creates a pointer that can also represent a Bar.

What I don't understand is what exactly z is.

- Is it a Bar? And if so, how can it be given Bar's only constructor?
- Is it a Bar sized chunk of memory belonging to instances of Foo that  can be initialized into a Bar?
- Or is it something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried compiling your example?  That might provide you with some insight. (It at least would answer your "how" question with "It can't.")

Comment: With Bar& x, you have to assign x at construction of Foo.

Comment: I believe a default constructor is being called. Edit: never mind, there is no default constructor if a user defines one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pedagogical reasons, let's try to compile this code:

```
class Bar {
public:
    Bar(int bunchOfCrap, int thatNeedsToBeHere, double toMakeABar);
};

class Foo {
public:
    Bar &x; // <- This is a ref, Bar is not instantiated (this is just a placeholder)
    Bar *y; // <- This is a pointer, Bar is not instantiated (this is just a *safer* placeholder)
    Bar z;  // <- What is this???
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
}
```

Output:

```
c++     uuu.cpp   -o uuu
uuu.cpp:10:7: error: implicit default constructor for 'Foo' must explicitly initialize the reference member 'x'
class Foo {
      ^
uuu.cpp:14:10: note: declared here
    Bar &x; // <- This is a ref, Bar is not instantiated (this is just a placeholder)
         ^
uuu.cpp:10:7: error: implicit default constructor for 'Foo' must explicitly initialize the member 'z' which does not
      have a default constructor
class Foo {
      ^
uuu.cpp:16:9: note: member is declared here
    Bar z;  // <- What is this???
        ^
uuu.cpp:2:7: note: 'Bar' declared here
class Bar {
      ^
uuu.cpp:21:9: note: implicit default constructor for 'Foo' first required here
    Foo foo;
        ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [uuu] Error 1
```

As it says, you *must* initialize both the member reference `Bar &x` and the member variable `Bar z;`, because `Bar` doesn't have a default constructor. `y` doesn't have to be initialized, and it will default to `NULL`.

Both `x` and `y` indirectly refer to the object. You can't change what `x` refers to (so it must be initialized when `Foo` is instantiated). You can change what `y` refers to. `z` is a `Bar`-sized chunk of memory which lives inside `Foo`; for you to legally declare a member variable like this, you have to put the complete definition of `Bar` before `Foo` so that the compiler knows how big `Bar` is.

Answer (score 1):

`z` is an instance of `Bar`, and must be constructed when `Foo` is, thus:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(…)
        : x(<instance of or reference to Bar>),
          y(<pointer to Bar>), // optional
          z(<Bar ctor params>)
    { … }
```

Note that both `x` and `z` must be initialized during construction, whereas it is legal (albeit questionable) to omit `y`'s initialization.

`z` occupies the same memory as the parent `Foo` instance, but it is an instance of `Bar`, not just a `Bar`-sized chunk of memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes it is a bar: `z` is a **value** identifier of type `Bar`. This will generate a compiler error if you have not defined a default constructor (the compiler normally does this but it won't if you have defined at least one construction -> which you have).
2. Yes it is a Bar sized chunk of memory, allocated when `Foo` is allocated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a Bar? And if so, how can it be given Bar's only constructor?

Yes, z is a bar. If `Bar` has no default constructor you have to initialize `Bar` in Foo `member initializers list`. Below sample ignores x, y initialization:

```
Foo::Foo(int param1, int param2, int param3)
: z(param1, param2, param3)
{
}
```

> Is it a Bar sized chunk of memory belonging to instances of Foo that can be initialized into a Bar?

Yes, Bar object is aligned inside Foo object